# Why do internal classes have to be imported?

Tags: java, import, ide

In any IDE, when working with a class in a package and I need to use a class from another one, I have to import it. Why doesn't the IDE just automatically import the packages so there is no need to do it manually?

Comment: Just import everything with the creation of a new class instead of having to do it manually

Comment: In most IDEs you can auto import - for example in Netbeans in windows Ctrl+shift+i...

Comment: What I meant is why the IDE does not automatically import all classes that you have created (not external libraries). It is very annoying to import every time you need a class outside the package you are working on

Comment: Hi there @user3285825. Are you answering your own question? I don't understand your comment then about importing everything. Were you aware that you can specify the fully qualified class name instead of importing the package? Like what @peter.petrov mentions below; for example `java.util.Date` would explicitly specify to use that Date.

Comment: Tip: You can use the ASTERISK character (*) as a wildcard, to reduce the number of `import` lines. For example, using the single line [`java.time.*`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) to import all the new time-related classes in Java 8, rather than multiple lines for individual classes such as [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), [`java.time.ZoneId`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, In Eclipse, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to automatically import anything you need.

From the [java package tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html):

> For convenience, the Java compiler automatically imports two entire
>   packages for each source file: (1) the java.lang package and (2) the
>   current package (the package for the current file).

The IDE will not import all your packages because 1.

1. You may not need them, why import them?
2. More importantly, you can have classes in different packages with the same name, then this will cause name ambiguities.

> If a member in one package shares its name with a member in another
>   package and both packages are imported, you must refer to each member
>   by its qualified name. For example, the graphics package defined a
>   class named Rectangle. The java.awt package also contains a Rectangle
>   class. If both graphics and java.awt have been imported, the following
>   is ambiguous.

This would cause unnecessary headache making sure you are always referring to the correct package. By importing packages and classes yourself, you can be sure that you are always using the specific class that you intended to.

Answer (score 2):

Because sometimes different classes have same 'short' name so the IDE does not know which one you meant. For example if you copy-paste code into your IDE containing `Date`, it does not know if you meant `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date`. In these cases the IDE will offer you to choose from all available classes with that name.

Answer (score 0):

This is my thought. Think this way,

Suppose you have two classes having the same name in different packages like this, then how does IDE resolve the package import? How does it know which SendFormAction to be imported?
So generally IDE's give you an option to import the packages [cntrl+shift+O in eclipse IDE]
and if there is confusion, it will ask you which one to import.

```
com.xyz.action [package]
SendFormAction.java

com.abc.action [package]
SendFormAction.java
```